# Active Links in Gatsby seems broken with trailing slashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to highlight my item when I'm on the right page, so I'm using this code :

```
const isActive = ({ isCurrent }) => {
  return isCurrent ? { className: "active" } : null
}
<Link getProps={isActive} to="/post">Articles</Link>
```

It works for `/post` but doesn't work for `/post/`

How to fix that for both case please?

---

I'm using :

`gatsby-link`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-link

which use: https://reach.tech/router/example/active-links

Comment: Could you please add a bit more code? I tried to run it locally but then I'm getting error: `React does not recognize the getProps prop on a DOM element.`

Comment: @DominikKrzywiecki okay thanks. I update my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is a plugin https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes which will remove trailing slashes from URL and I believe that this is the right solution.

If for some reason you don't want to install this dependency, you can customize your `isActive` function, get `href` param and compare with `window.location.pathname` (firstly remove the trailing slash from last one) and then this will also work but I strongly recommend the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby v2 removes the need for that function.

The code base and examples are sprinkled with the function version, but the better way is to use `partiallyActive` and the `activeStyle` props.

```
    <Link
      to="/post"
      partiallyActive={true}
      activeStyle={styles.active}
    >
      Articles
    </Link>
```

```
  const styles = {
    active: {
      borderBottomColor: `#663399`,
      color: `#663399`,
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works for me, care to elaborate why you believe this

Comment: My bad. This used to be an issue but I just did a test with the latest Gatsby and looks like it's working.

Comment: In Gatsby v4, at least, a link to `/` will be shown as active when on `/post` or `/post/`, so `partiallyActive={true}` doesn't seem like a good solution for this.

Comment: Is Gatsby even a thing anymore?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue. Is it back? E.g., `/photography` is active, but `/photography/` isn't.